# Trying to understand .bashrc, .profile, etc.. files

Tags: bash, login, profile

I am trying to understand the relation among the files .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile, etc... as well as the meaning of login/non login shells, interactive/non interactive shells, etc...

Every information I found is too abstract while what I want is a concrete practical explanation.

So my questions are (related to a linux system like Ubuntu)

1. What files are executed when the system is started up and I login to it (graphical desktop shows up)?
2. What files are executed when I open a terminal emulator?
3. What files are executed when I login in a text console (after pressing Ctrl-Alt-Fn)
4. In what other events any of those files are executed?
5. How can an interactive login shell may be started?
6. How can a non interactive login shell may be started?
7. How can a interactive non login shell may be started?
8. How can a non interactive non login shell may be started?

Feel free to answer just some of the questions... Thanks...

Comment: Read `man bash`, the section on "Startup files". Q1 (system startup) is different and complex, use Google. Read the Help section of AskUbuntu and don't ask multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

First, see waltinator's comment. However, to answer some of your questions (conceptually more so than technical accuracy)..

1. None of the normal shell files get loaded when you log in to a GUI. They are loaded when you log in to TUI (text only) shell or a terminal program from the GUI. In ruth, the GUI is itself a shell much like bash, except that it gives you a graphical interface instead of a text one. It also has it's own configuration files and startup files.
2. The exact files that get loaded depend on the shell. See the documentation for the shell you are using.
3. See above. The virtual terminals and the terminal programs from the GUI both go the same route: They result in you logging in to whichever shell is defined as your primary login shell (defined/configured in /etc/passwd for your user name).

Same for almost all of the questions, really.

The job of a shell is to execute other programs. They can be internal programs for the shell (internal commands), instruction files for the shell (shell scripts, much like DOS batch files), or other applications/programs installed in the system (external programs). It can also operate in many different modes; interactive mode means it will display a command prompt and wait for you to type a command. Non-interactive mode means when the shell was started, it was given a shell script to execute, and it gets it's commands from the script instead of you typing them.

Another important thing to understand is that on a un*x system, a shell is programmed almost as if you are sending it commands over the internet from the far side of the planet. Even when you are sitting right in front of the computer--It still treats your login session as if it was over the network. This is why it always acts the same regardless of whether it's a terminal, console, network, ssh/telnet, TUI/GUI, serial, or any kind of log in you can imagine. Perhaps one day we will even have telepathic log in--but the shell will still act as if it's a normal log in, and still work the same way that it does now.

One last point about "non log in" shells; They are the same thing as well. The only difference as far as you are concerned is that you can start one *from* an already logged in shell without having to log in again (entering your name and password).

Of course, many of the technical details of all this are a little different and have both obvious and subtle side effects and implications. But that is really where you will need to go search the web for resources and sites that go in to deeper detail on how shells work.